# How can I change Facebook comment iframe position?

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-comments

In my Wordpress blog, I want to change the Facebook comment iframe position in my single posts.

It is currently at the end of the post but I want to move it to under the line to the "No Comments yet." part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added the code in the  wrong position.

You need to remove the code from inside `<div class="entry">` place and move it the bottom inside of `<div id="comments">`.

*If you provide us with the simplified code you are using, we can show you where it needs to be placed.*

*Update: Since you are using wordpress, then you may have to contact the developer to ask them to change it. If you are using placeable code, then please show us.*

Comment: Do you need facebook's code or wordpress's ? I am using official facebook wordpress plugin.

Comment: At @Omarlthawi's suggestion of using the actual Facebook comments code is probably the best way to go about this. That would probably be easier, but if you want to use a wordpress plugin, then link me to it (if you can find it on the wordpress website) and I will have a look. From there I will have a think how to solve the problem.

Comment: You can use the link -> https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B6RtH22X-5tKM19SLVNYdFlVTW8 these are the wordpress plugin's whole files. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I took a look, but I don't have time now to sort it the complicated way. For the time being, your best bet would be, as said before, to use the actual code Facebook provided here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/ and add this in the correct position on the code. If you go into your actual wordpress theme files, and upload them to a public hosting site (I recommended dropbox(http://db.tt/fmsfcc6B )(note: affiliate link) then I will show you where to add it and/or upload the modified file.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Jason said, 1) ask the developer or 2) edit the plugin yourself (kinda hard).

3) Use the Facebook comments https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/ and place it as you like!